# 3d bar plot of lists using matplotlib, pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have 3 lists

```
 def main():
     x = np.arange(0.0,256.0)
     y = np.arange(0.0,256.0)
     Y,X = np.meshgrid(x,y)
     Z = wron(X,Y)
     for i in range(0,256):
         Z[i][0]=0

 def wron(X,Y):
     t=X/Y
     return(abs(t*(t-1)))
```

How do i get the 3d bar plot of X,Y and Z lists. where X,Y,Z corresponds to x,y,z axes.

I tried the following code.

```
 from pylab import *
 import numpy
 from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

 def main():
   fig=figure()
   ax=Axes3D(fig)
   x=np.arange(0.0,256.0)
   y=np.arange(0.0,256.0)
   Y,X= np.meshgrid(x,y)
   Z=wron(X,Y)
   for i in range(0,256):
     Z[i][0]=0
   ax.bar(X,Y,zs=Z,zdir='y')
   show()
 def wron(X,Y):
   t=X/Y
   return(abs(t*(t-1)))

 if __name__=='__main__':
   main()
```

But i get this error:

```
patches = Axes.bar(self, left, height, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 4887, in bar
 if h<0:
  ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Look into `mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D`.

Comment: See http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/hist3d_demo.html